# Initializing string in a do-while loop will jump to it before checking condition

Tags: c++, string, do-while

I have encountered this problem where the condition might reject the string, and it needed to be generated again (it's a random string)

```
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string str;
    do{
        std::string str{""};
        str.append("foo");
    }
    while( str != "foo" );

    return 0;
}
```

I expect that str will be equal to "foo" and the program will continue, but it doesn't. It gets stuck. Upon inspection with gdb, I noticed that it jumps from `str.append("foo");` back to `std::string str{""};` and only *then* proceeding to checking the condition, therefore the condition will never be met. why does this happen?

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You have a duplicate `str` variable inside the loop:

```
std::string str;
do{
    std::string str{""}; // <----- here
    str.append("foo");
}
while( str != "foo" );
```

This makes it so that the `while` loop is checking the first `str`, as the `str` inside the loop is not within scope, which is never changed.

Inside the `while` loop you are modifying the second `str` variable because (From the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)):

> Actual scope is the same as potential scope unless there is a nested block with a declaration that introduces identical name (in which case, the entire potential scope of the nested declaration is excluded from the scope of the outer declaration)

To fix this, just remove the line `std::string str{""};` from your code. If you need it to be reset, modify `str` instead of creating a new one:

```
std::string str;
do{
    str = "";
    str.append("foo");
}
while( str != "foo" );
```